# how to concenate a list of value based on some criteria in spreadhseet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image]

so i want to concat a list of value in column K if the condition in column J and G are true.

im expecting that a can get the list of that and seperate it with coma like i already put it in column A - E, the formula will be in column B and im expecting to use the formula with the help of arrayformula. Im also put a note on cell B2 for some short explanation you can check it here :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LwdHmtQhr5YlHzMw6DOcpYW0v1XfCgHCf1CSk9-xF6k/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what columns among the whole  range of *A-K* are the input(s) & Columns *A-E* are the expected output?! `if the condition in column J and G are true` bit unclear on what are these conditions!

Comment: so if the contents of columns J and G are the same then column H will produce output from the list owned by column K, the formula will be filled in column K and my expectations are as in column B

Comment: in columns A - K the inputs are in column A, D, E

Comment: In this particular case you may use `=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(K:K,J:J=x))))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin(", ",1,ifna(filter(E:E,D:D=Σ))))))
```

[image]